# Mirror modifier not working properly with shrinkwrap (retopology)

Tags: mirror, shrinkwrap

Some parts of the body mirror in a wrong way and i don't know how to solve it, it's the first time that happens
[image]

Comment: 13 milion of vertices, why/how? 
First of you could to flip normals it seems like some of them are fliped, then you should provide screenshot from edit mode just so we can see topology.

Edit: try moving shrikwrap modifier to top, and moving other modifiers too, it is probably because of them.

Comment: @BlackCloud 13millions verts are from the high poly cloth and body

Comment: Yes I know, I was saying it is a lot. 
Did you tried to change order of modifiers, does it help?